# Why does the number 0 evaluate to a blank space

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

This is something that has baffled me before but I have never found an explanation for it. I have a column in a SQL Server 2008 database that is of type `smallint`. I want to look for any rows where the value is `NULL` or blank, so I say this:

```
SELECT *
FROM products
WHERE warranty_dom IS NULL
OR warranty_dom = ''
```

This returns rows with a value of 0

So why is `0` treated as the equivalent of `''` ?

Comment: How can it be *blank* if it's a smalint?

Comment: That is not a _blank space_, by the way. It is an _empty string_.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

0 is not treated as '' per se. Instead, '' is implicitly cast to an integer, and that cast makes it 0.

Try it yourself:

```
SELECT CAST(0 AS varchar)        -- Output: '0'
SELECT CAST('' AS smallint)      -- Output: 0
```

Also, as mentioned elsewhere: If warranty_dom is of type smallint, then it's not possible for it to be blank in the first place.

Comment: Thanks, I am an idiot I guess.....I was so accustomed to always checking for both NULL and blank strings the absurdity of doing it for numerical fields did not occur to me....